# issues loading items from firebase to a pickerview

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have successfully created a QuestionModel class which retrieves items from firebase such, as a Question, string of answers and a correct question. I am however now having difficulty in terms of getting these items to go into a picker view from another class. The class called QuestionsViewController is where I am having an issue in terms of using the questions class to retrieve data from. The QuestionModel class contains retrieving data from firebase. I am having bad execution errors throughout the code in the QuestionsViewController class. This mainly occurs when trying to set the itemlabel text before the pickverview and code for the pickerview functions.

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth
import CoreData

class QuestionList
{
//properties
public static var Username: String = ""
private static var quiz = [Question]()

static func getDummyQuestions()->[Question]
{
    //create some dummy data for the model
    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
    var refHandle: UInt!
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference() //reference

    refHandle = ref.child("Questions").child("Q1").observe(.value,       with: { (snapshot)in
        if let dataDict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {

            if let quest = dataDict["Question"] as? String,
                let Answers = dataDict["Answers"] as? [String],
                let Correct = dataDict["Correct"] as? Int {
                quiz.append(Question(q: quest, a: Answers, c: Correct))
            }
            print (dataDict)
        }
    })
    return quiz
  } 
}


class Question {
  var quest:String
  var answers:[String]
  var correct:Int

  init(q: String, a:[String], c:Int)
  {
      quest = q
      answers = a
      correct = c
  }

  func isCorrectQuestion(itemSelected: String)->Bool {
      if (itemSelected == answers[correct]) {
          return true
      } else {
          return false
      }
  }
}

import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

class QuestionsViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var usernamelabel: UILabel! //sets username label
@IBOutlet weak var Next: UIButton! //next button
@IBOutlet weak var itemLabel: UILabel! //item user has selected
@IBOutlet weak var Question: UILabel! //sets question label
@IBOutlet weak var pickerview: UIPickerView! //sets picker view

public var totalQuestions: Int = 0 //sets total question to 0
public var currentQuestion = 0  //sets current question to 0
public var totalCorrect: Int = 0 //sets totalcorrect to 0
var itemSelected: String = "" //item selected
var LabelText = String()
let Exam = QuestionList() //uses the questions class for instances
var Questions = QuestionList.getDummyQuestions()

var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
var refHandle: UInt!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() //when the app is loaded

    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference() //reference
    refHandle = ref.child("Questions").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot)in
        let dataDict = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
        print (dataDict)
    })
     usernamelabel.text = LabelText //username

    pickerview.delegate = self

    itemLabel.text = "" //loads the item label of whats selected
    itemSelected = QuestionList.getDummyQuestions()[currentQuestion].answers[0] //initially when loaded first item is selected
    Question.text = QuestionList.getDummyQuestions()[currentQuestion].quest
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1 //return one component from the picker
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
    return QuestionList.getDummyQuestions()[currentQuestion].answers.count  
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int,    forComponent component: Int) -> String?{
    return QuestionList.getDummyQuestions().  [currentQuestion].answers[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){

    itemSelected = QuestionList.getDummyQuestions(). [currentQuestion].answers[row]
}

@IBAction func NextAction(_ sender: Any){

   currentQuestion = currentQuestion + 1 //moves onto next question and   increments

    if (QuestionList.getDummyQuestions()[currentQuestion].isCorrectQuestion(itemSelected: itemSelected)) {
        totalCorrect += 1
        itemLabel.text = String(totalCorrect) + "/" + String(totalQuestions)
    }

    if(currentQuestion < QuestionList.getDummyQuestions().count) {
        pickerview.reloadAllComponents()
        itemSelected = QuestionList.getDummyQuestions()[currentQuestion].answers[1]
        Question.text = QuestionList.getDummyQuestions() [currentQuestion].quest
    } else {
        pickerview.isHidden = true
        Question.text = "You have finished"
        Next.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please only post relevant code.

Comment: All of the code is relevant as it all works together

Answer (score 1):

Firebase functions do not (and should not) return values as they are asynchronous.

So the return quiz line will fail most of the time as it will try to return data before Firebase has had time to retrieve it from the server.

When coding with Firebase, data is only valid inside the closure following the function. So for example, this what NOT to do:

```
func someFunc() {
    ref.child("Questions").child("Q1").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
      print(snap)
    })

    print(snap) //this will not print the snap as this line executes *before* the closure
}
```

So doing it the right way; retrieve the data from Firebase, populate the array and refresh the tableview all within the closure.

```
static func populateArrayAndRefreshTableView()
{
    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!= FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let questionsRef = ref.child("Questions")

    questionsRef.child("Q1").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        if let dataDict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
            let quest = dataDict["Question"] as? String,
            let Answers = dataDict["Answers"] as? [String],
            let Correct = dataDict["Correct"] as? Int {
            self.quizArray.append(Question(q: quest, a: Answers, c: Correct))
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    })
  } 
}
```

Also note that the original code was using observe(.value). That will leave an observer attached to the ref and if the question changes, the code will be called. It doesn't look like that should be the behavior so using observeSingleEvent will call it once without adding an observer.

Finally - you may want to re-consider how the nodes are named in your structure. It's often best practice to disassociate node name keys from the data they contain.

```
questions
   -UYiuokoksokda
      question: "What significant contribution to bioengineering was made on the Loonkerian outpost on Klendth?"
      correct_answer: answer_1
      answers:
        answer_0: "Left handed smoke shifter"
        answer_1: "The universal atmospheric element compensator"
        answer_2: "Warp coil nullification amplifier"
        answer_3: "H.A.L. 9000"
   -YY8jioijasdjd
      question: "What is Kiri-kin-tha's first law of metaphysics?"
      correct_answer: answer_2
      answers:
        answer_0: "No matter where you go, there you are"
        answer_1: "Only people with sunroofs use them"
        answer_2: "Nothing unreal exists"
        answer_3: "Gravity is heavy"
```

The keys, UYiuokoksokda, are created with childByAutoId().

If you need to query answers you may want to even denormalize them into their own node and use the question key as the node key for the answers or keep a child node with the question key.

Comment: But I am using a picker view to fetch data so how would I use the code for that?

Comment: A picker view doesn't fetch data. It presents existing data from a dataSource, such as an array, to the user via a spinning wheel interface. You can store whatever you want in the array - in your case you are storing Question class objects. Once the array is populated, you can call reloadAllComponents to reload the pickerView - just like it would be done with a tableView. See Apples's documentation [UIPickerView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipickerview)

Comment: Okay thanks but what I dont get is how to access this data from the pickerview? I have set the functions for the pickerview however am having an error in regards to a execution error

Comment: Well, the Firebase component it working and you are able to populate the array being used as a datasource. So the only task left it to implement the pickerView delegate functions. It's too big of a question to be answered here but if you google *UIPIckerView tutorial* the first link or two are very good and will walk you through the process.

Comment: @minalmodi That's a little vague, what error? On what line? I copy and and pasted the code in my answer from an existing project and it works with the structure I suggested.